# ag-grid enterprise custom footer excel and CSV from context menu export

Tags: excel, csv, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

ag-grid enterprise custom footer excel and CSV from context menu export

I have added defaultExportParams where it is working fine for excel but for CSV I am getting [object Object]

```
customFooter: [
  [],
  [
    {
      data: {
        type: 'String'
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        type: 'String'
      }
    },

    {
      styleId: 'watermark',
      data: {
        type: 'String',
        value: 'My Own Footer Value'
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

};

If I try like this, CSV is working but failing for excel customFooter : '[[[ My Own Footer Value ]]]\n'. How can I achieve this for both CSV, EXCEL for context menu export

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you share your code via  plnkr or stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining

```
data: {
    type: 'String'
}
```

You have to define a `value` also (or you will get an error)

So remove unused definitions or append the values (empty string is possible)

```
data: {
    type: 'String',
    value: ''
}
```

Comment: This will work only for Excel not for both excel and CSV

Comment: why not create a condition to handle CSV and Excel separately?